# fgets not storing the supplied inputs in the destination variables

Tags: c, fgets

When I run this code:

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<stdlib.h>

int main()
{
    char name , age , gender , male;

    printf("Please enter your name \n");

    fgets(name, 20 ,stdin);

    printf("Please enter your age \n");

    fgets(age , 2 , stdin);

    printf("Please enter your gender \n");

    fgets(gender , 7 , stdin);

    atoi(age);

    {
        if (age < 50 && gender == male)

            printf(" You're fit to play\n Welcome player ,%s \n",name);

            else printf("Sorry , %s. You're not fit to play", name);

    }
    return 0;
}
```

I get this output:

```
please enter your name
please enter your age
please enter your gender
you're fit to play
welcome player, (null)
```

And these are the warnings i get from the compiler in my codeblocks:

```
||=== Build: Release in justexploring1 (compiler: GNU GCC Compiler) ===|
D:\Project\C language\justexploring1\main.c||In function `main':|
D:\Project\C language\justexploring1\main.c|8|warning: passing arg 1 of `fgets' makes pointer from integer without a cast|
D:\Project\C language\justexploring1\main.c|10|warning: passing arg 1 of `fgets' makes pointer from integer without a cast|
D:\Project\C language\justexploring1\main.c|12|warning: passing arg 1 of `fgets' makes pointer from integer without a cast|
D:\Project\C language\justexploring1\main.c|13|warning: passing arg 1 of `atoi' makes pointer from integer without a cast|
D:\Project\C language\justexploring1\main.c|16|warning: format argument is not a pointer (arg 2)|
D:\Project\C language\justexploring1\main.c|17|warning: format argument is not a pointer (arg 2)|
D:\Project\C language\justexploring1\main.c|6|warning: 'name' might be used uninitialized in this function|
D:\Project\C language\justexploring1\main.c|6|warning: 'age' might be used uninitialized in this function|
D:\Project\C language\justexploring1\main.c|6|warning: 'gender' might be used uninitialized in this function|
D:\Project\C language\justexploring1\main.c|6|warning: 'male' might be used uninitialized in this function|
||=== Build finished: 0 error(s), 10 warning(s) (0 minute(s), 0 second(s)) ===|
```

It totally ignores `fgets` and doesn't prompt for any input.
always treats if statement as true.
and always uses (null) for `name`.

Could you please tell me what's wrong with my code?
I was once told to use `fgets` instead of `scanf` and `gets`. 
it's worth mentioning that `scanf` also gave me similar problems.

Comment: Do yourself a favour: **turn on all compiler warnings and heed them**.

Comment: I just added compiler warnings to the question. There's quite a bunch of them.

Comment: strcmp ? I don't know this function. Can u show me how it's used?

Comment: if strcmp (gender == male) ?

Comment: please read a good text/reference for the C language as we can't teach you C here

Comment: Actually my text book got me all confused because it says i could do this

Comment: if(temperature>70 && sun==shining && weekend==YES)

Comment: 1) It certainly does not. 2) Get a C book you understand better 3) From your previous questions, you really should get a new C book. 4) Or you skipped chapters. Just don't. 5) There are alternatives to programming ...

Answer (score 2):

In your code, `name`, `age`, `gender`, `male` all are `char` variables, not `char` array. You'll be needing an array to achieve what you're targeting. Your arrays need to be of the same size as of that what you pass to `fgets()`.

That said,

- [`atoi()`](http://linux.die.net/man/3/atoi) does not convert the supplied string itself to `int`, it returns the converted value. You have to store that in a variable.
- `male` is a *variable*, not a *string literal*, so the variable name cannot be used as a *value* for comparison. You can either define a variable holding the string literal, `const char * match = "male";` or directly use the string literal itself (`"male"`) for comparison.
- You need to use [`strcmp()`](http://linux.die.net/man/3/strcmp) for comparing strings, anyway.

Comment: So how do I convert the value into integer? Or how do I prompt for an integer ?

Comment: @AllanMayers You can store the return value of `atoi()` into an `int` variable, if you want.

Comment: @AllanMayers Here is a [demo](http://ideone.com/RKL2VT) that should work for you.  I don't think it's right to discriminate against gender, but against people who don't like pancakes...definitely :-) (take a look at the demo if you don't understand what I meant there)!  It should be easy to change back, though.  I hope that helps you!

Comment: @AllanMayers I'm happy that we were able to help you.