# Why is declaring a struct pointer preventing file reads?

Tags: c

I'm trying to learn about file handling in C right now, and I'm having an issue with seemingly unrelated things.

I have a text file containing some usernames and I'm trying to open the file for reading and print the first username in the file. It works fine when I run the code and file that follow:

**file_read.c**

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

struct list_node {
    char *value;
    struct list_node *next;
};

int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {
    if (argc <= 1) {
        printf("Usage: a.out <file containing usernames>\n");
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    }
    printf("%d\n", argc);
    printf("%s\n", *argv);
    printf("%s\n", *(argv+1));

    FILE *file = fopen(*(argv+1), "r");
    if (!file) {
        printf("Could not open file\n");
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    }

    char *curr_username;
    int status = fscanf(file, "%s", curr_username);
    if (!curr_username || status == EOF) {
        printf("File is empty\n");
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    } else {
        printf("first username was: %s\n", curr_username);
    }
    struct list_node first_node = {curr_username, NULL};
    /*struct list_node *last_node = &first_node;*/

    fclose(file);

    exit(EXIT_SUCCESS);
}
```

**usernames.txt**

```
me@host
you@host
him@host
her@host
```

**usage**

```
./a.out usernames.txt
```

When I run the program as shown in "usage", it prints the following:

```
2
./a.out
usernames.txt
first username was: me@host
```

In the code snippet you can see there's a line commented out that is supposed to declare a struct pointer. My next step is to read all usernames into a simple linked list. Hence, I'm using a pointer to store the previous item in the list.

When I uncomment this line, however, and recompile and run the program, the output changes to this:

```
2
./a.out
usernames.txt
File is empty
```

What is happening here? Is this optimization doing something I don't want, or am I triggering some sort of undefined behavior somewhere, or something else entirely?

I'm compiling with GCC version 4.1.2 with no options.

Comment: `fscanf(file, "%s", curr_username)` is reading into unallocated and uninitialized pointer.

Comment: `char *curr_username` -> `char curr_username[100]`

Comment: @Jabberwocky and then the `!curr_username` condition becomes meaningless

Comment: @EugeneSh. yes of course, I didn't check any further.

Comment: Forgot to mention: your are experiencing _undefined behaviour_ (google that).

Comment: Possible duplicate of [fgets not storing the supplied inputs in the destination variables](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39083110/fgets-not-storing-the-supplied-inputs-in-the-destination-variables)

Comment: Don't use GCC with no options.  Use `gcc -std=c11 -Wall -Wextra -Werror` at a bare minimum — specify the current standard (use `-std=gnu11` if you prefer) and make sure you get errors for the silly mistakes the compiler can spot.  I'd add more options to that list `-Wmissing-prototypes -Wstrict-prototypes -Wold-style-declaration -Wold-style-definition` (some of which may not be supported by an archaic compiler such as GCC 4.1.2).  Actually, come to think of it, it's so old it may not support C11; you may be stuck with C99 instead.  But never use GCC without warnings enabled.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This line:

```
int status = fscanf(file, "%s", curr_username);
```

Writes data to `curr_username` which is not initialised and has no defined storage space or address.  The consequence is non-deterministic such that even apparently unrelated code changes can change the behaviour.  The behaviour following this invalid memory access will depend on what memory/address is accessed and how that memory is subsequently used.

The behaviour is undefined and non-deterministic, but typically you will see:

- a memory fault exception and crash,
- errant behaviour in other unrelated code,
- code appearing to work normally (latent bug).

In your case you have observed the latter two of these.

In this line:

```
if (!curr_username || status == EOF)
```

testing `curr_username` for null makes no sense - `scanf` does not modify the pointer.  One might guess that the addition of the new variable caused `curr_username` to be instantiated in memory that happened in this case to contain zero, so the condition becomes true, whereas previously it contained a non-zero value that just happened to be a writable memory address.

Answer (score 1):

Here are the few observation from the code you mentioned.

- As pointed by @EugeneSh in comments in the statement

  ```
     fscanf(file, "%s", curr_username);
  ```

  you are reading from `file` & storing into `curr_username` which is not initialized or not having valid memory to store, so this causes **undefined behavior** in your code.

  Allocate the memory for `curr_username` & then scan using `fscanf()`. for e.g

  `char *curr_username = malloc(MAX_STR_SIZE); /* define the MAX_STR_SIZE   */`

  And once done, free the dynamically allocated memory by calling `free()` to avoid memory leakage. for e.g

  `free(curr_username);`

Comment: Your first point is a comment on the code, not an answer to the question - example usage is provided and in that case at least the input is valid - argc need not be _exactly_ 2 for the code to run in any case - extraneous arguments will not cause failure - the point is a matter of opinion not an answer - there may be valid reasons for allowing more arguments - this code is apparently not yet complete.  It certainly should not be your _first_ point, since it is unrelated to the failure observed. Your second point is the answer, and perhaps deserves the prominence of being first.

Comment: Agree @Clifford Thanks for pointing that. Shall I remove first point completely or re-order.

Comment: I'd remove it and if you feel strongly about it add a comment to the _question_.